# Force my heroku app to use SSL (https)

Tags: heroku, https

I have a node app running successfully on Heroku. I have purchased an Expedited SSL certificate and it all works fine. I go to https... and get a full 'green bar' proving the site is being served over https

However, the non-SSL standard http is still available too. How can I force the app to serve over https? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add to the Node.js app the code to redirect the request to the HTTPS version if the request comes from HTTP.

Depending on the framework or the tools you use, the idea is simple:

- check the request scheme
- if http, redirect to https passing along the same request uri and query

Comment: Official doc entry: [can Heroku force an application to use ssl?](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls) this article shows you how to implement that redirect at app level using different framework/languages

Answer (score 48):

On Heroku, it's slightly tricky to determine the fact that the request came in over http.  https is handled at a heroku routing layer and it passes along the request to the node app on http).

This post got me unstuck http://jaketrent.com/post/https-redirect-node-heroku/

Comment: bro i've been trying to figure this out for 4 months straight, you are god, i owe you my life, thank you.

Comment: The last code block in that article works really well! But rememeber to put it **first** of all of express' `app.use()`

Comment: @HolgerL aww, I wish I saw your reply earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

There's also NPM module [heroku-ssl-redirect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heroku-ssl-redirect) helping you to deal with it

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: Still works like a charm in 2019, had this issue with a Create-React-App on Heroku and a domain with GoDaddy. The express server serving the build needed this.

Comment: if you are using nextjs, i created a Middleware version of this package so you don't have to setup a custom server:  `next-ssl-redirect-middleware`

Comment: 2022 - doesn't work for me (`sslRedirect is not a function`)

Answer (score 26):

I just use the ["Always use HTTPS"-Feature](https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-make-your-site-https-only/) from Cloudflare for that. Just follow these steps:

**1.** [Sign Up](https://dash.cloudflare.com/sign-up) on Cloudflare if you haven't already

**2.** Add your site `example.com`

**3.** Select a plan. (Free plan is enough for that)

**4.** Review your DNS records. Cloudflare tries to automatically detect the records if you have already some entries at Namecheap for example. Whats important is that you leave at least the Type A record with the `IPv4` address and also the `CNAME` Type where the `Content` is the `DNS Target` from the Domain Name in the Heroku Settings of your App. See also the screenshot

[image: cloudflare_heroku]

**5.** You need to point Cloudflare's nameservers to activate your site successfully otherwise Cloudflare is unable to manage your DNS and optimize your site. Remove existing nameservers and then replace them with Cloudflare's nameservers. They will show you also the instructions on a page (Could take up to 48h until your site is active, but in my experience it took only 15mins). See the screenshot with Namecheap as example:

[image: cloudflare_namecheap]

**6.** Go to the `SSL/TLS` Section and under the section `Edge Certificates` enable the "Always Use HTTPS"-Feature. Now all requests with scheme "http" should be redirected to "https"

[image: cloudflare_https]

**Bonus 1:** To forward also requests without the scheme or www for example if the user enters just `example.com` or `www.example.com` just create a page rule to forward these requests to your secured url. For that go to the section "Page Rules" and hit the "Create Page Rule"-Button. Enter the url which should match and add the Setting `Forwarding URL` with the status code `301 - Permanent Redirect`. Enter also the destination url as follows with `$1` at the end to make it work correctly. Hit "Save and Deploy" and you're ready to go. For more details check the section "Advanced forwarding options" [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-Configuring-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare-Page-Rules) (Keep in mind that you may need to clear your cache to see the changes). See the screenshot:

[image: cloudflare_page_rule]

**Bonus 2:** You bought another domain and just want to redirect this to your secured main domain. For example you bought `fiveexample.com` and `5example.com` and you want to redirect `5example.com` always to `https://www.fiveexample.com` no matter what the user enters regarding `5example.com` e.g. `www.5example.com`, `http://5example.com` and even `https://www.5example.com` even if your second domain has no ssl. Cloudflares page rules are also here a solution. Just follow the steps 1-5 (but at step 4 you don't need the heroku dns target) for your second domain. After you followed the steps to support all forwardings add these three page rules for your second domain. Works also perfectly for `.app` domains (Keep in mind that you may need to clear your cache to see the changes). See screenshot

[image: redirect_second_domain_to_main_domain]

Comment: This is the best solution

Answer (score 19):

For anybody coming along to this post, I was having this problem and discovered that I had code in this order, which was screwing things up:

```
### old way
app.use(express.static('build'));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.header('x-forwarded-proto') !== 'https') {
    res.redirect(`https://${req.header('host')}${req.url}`)
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

### new way (just swap the order)
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.header('x-forwarded-proto') !== 'https') {
    res.redirect(`https://${req.header('host')}${req.url}`)
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
app.use(express.static('build'));
```

Once I moved the express.static('build') below that send app.use method everything worked!

Comment: Bro, you are awesome!

Comment: dude youre a life saver <3

Answer (score 11):

If you are developing a `creat-react-app` and happened to use `create-react-app-buildpack` to deploy to Heroku (I'm lazy...)

You can specify the following in your `static.json` file

```
{
  "https_only": true
}
```

https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#user-content-https-only

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS in the infrastructure layer too, requiring no changes to your application.

The [Edge CDN addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/edge) offers a "redirect HTTP to HTTPS" option.

It puts the AWS CloudFront CDN in front of your app which is handles the redirect.

The Heroku router doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

As of July 2019, Heroku supports HTTPS redirects to **OTHER DOMAINS OR SUBDOMAINS** (a redirect cannot point to itself). All you have to do is configure a URL record for your domain as outlined in [this post](https://changelog.dnsimple.com/announcing-https-support-for-dnsimple-redirector-107882). The full announcement can be found [here](https://blog.dnsimple.com/2019/07/https-redirector).

Answer (score 1):

There are **3 things** to note:-

1. **Heroku does NOT have in-built HTTP to HTTPS** automatic redirect feature.
2. Thus, to implement HTTP to HTTPS redirects for your app deployed to Heroku, **you will have to include application-level logic** instead. Fortunately, Express JS has an inbuilt feature for this. If you are using the node runtime, just mount the following middleware before all routes in the server file:-

```
 //HTTP to HTTPS automatic redirect
    const requireHTTPS = (req, res, next) => {
      if (!req.secure && req.get('x-forwarded-proto') !== 'https' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
        return res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);
      }
      next();
    }
    
    app.use(requireHTTPS);
```

3. If you don't want to use the above-mentioned application-level logic, then use **Cloudflare's Always On HTTPS** feature. This is a free feature but requires time to set up as you will have to create a Cloudflare account and use Cloudflare nameservers for your custom domain first.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we redirect http to https on Heroku ( we have more than 100 domains pointing to the same site and some are not on SSL hence the domains are also tested in this case. If you don't need that just don't include the domain lines ) :

```
# Determine if http/https (when behind Heroku proxy it uses X-Forwarded-Proto header to detect)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:http]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.exampledomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.otherdomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)?.herokuapp.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:https]
```

There may be room for improvement on this but its been working great for us.

We have a LOT more lines after this block that redirects in other ways so we don't use the L flag at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Using nodejs and express:

```
const app = express();

app.enable('trust proxy');
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.secure) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
  }
});
```