# Redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com: Namecheap and Heroku

Tags: redirect, heroku, dns, namecheap

I'm trying to redirect all requests to:

```
https://example.com
http://www.example.com
http://example.com
```

to `https://www.example.com`. I'm using Heroku and Namecheap.

Here are my steps:

1. In Heroku, I added `www.example.com` to my domains, and enabled SSL.
2. On Namecheap, I created a `CNAME` record with host `www` to `www.example.com.herokudns.com.`
3. On Namecheap, I created a `URL Redirect` record with host `@` to `https://www.example.com/`.

With these steps, everything works well as long as I redirect `http` requests to `https` requests on the server side (e.g. redirect `http://www.example.com/` to `https://www.example.com/`).

The only thing I can't figure out is how to redirect `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`. From what I've read, it looks like this is what an `ALIAS` record could accomplish. Unfortunately, Namecheap doesn't seem to have this type of record available.

Is it possible get this behavior using Namecheap, or do I have to use a different DNS provider?

Comment: What is your web server? do you have access to a `.htaccess` file?

Comment: This is what I would like to figure out. @hetelek any luck on this in the past two years? Thank you!

Comment: A related question/answer, which is for GitHub but it might also work for Heroku: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9123911/3345375

Comment: Checkout this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58144352/5327882

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that is still having this issue, I found a solution with Namecheap for redirecting the root domain to a subdomain.

1. I pointed my subdomain e.g `www.example.com` to my website location (Github pages in this case)
2. I created a CNAME record for @ host and made its value my subdomain

This redirects my root domain to my subdomain.